# App settings appear in simulator but not on device?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

Hey folks, I'm setting up my first application settings bundle right now. I went through the process of creating a `Settings.bundle` in the project root, settings the `Root.plist` to display as an iPhone Settings plist, etc.

So – the app's settings panel displays in `Settings.app` just as I would expect in the iPhone Simulator. However, it is not present in my device settings when I deploy there. My test device is an iPod Touch running iOS4. I've rebooted the device just to make sure everything has reloaded... still nothing. Can anyone think of a reason that my settings panel would work in the Simulator but not on my Device?

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to run your app at least once after installing your app before the app's setting will appear.

Not sure if a quit and restart of the Settings app (from the "multi-tasking" bar) might also be required.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this myself - it usually happens when you mistype a key in the plist or if required keys are missing.

Comment: Cool, thanks... you don't happen to know what the required keys are, do you?

Comment: just check the documentation for that: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Preferences/Preferences.html