# App settings missing on device, present on simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, settings

I'm new to iOS development and testing on device for the first time. My App settings are not listed in the iOS settings app on the device (iOS6), but work as expected on the simulator (both iOS6 and iOS7).

I've seen:
[App settings appear in simulator but not on device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935658/app-settings-appear-in-simulator-but-not-on-device)

But starting then closing the app and rebooting doesn't resolve the problem, and I can't see any issues with the root.plist file.

Any advice on where to look or how to investigate it further would be much appreciated. I'm at a loss how to debug this one.

Comment: check you development certificate with your app bundle identifier.. are they correct?

Answer (score 0):

Completely remove the app from your device, clean your Xcode project and then rebuild it.
I recommend doing this every time you change something in your settings bundle.

Comment: Sorry for not replying before. In my case this didn't solve the problem, but thanks for the advice anyway. I copies the settings bundle code, deleted the file, recreated it and copied the code back in and all worked. No idea what the cause of the problem was though.